# Apache Redirect not working (issue with lowercase/uppercase + slash)

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

The URL with uppercase and slash is working but uppercase without slash is not working. However, lowercase has no problem with or without a slash. Everything need to redirect to `www.domain.com/name/homepage.html`

Ex:

```
www.domain.com/Name  - Do not work
www.domain.com/Name/ - Works
www.domain.com/name  - works
www.domain.com/name/ - works
```

Here are the rewrite rules/conditions I applied.

```
 RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1}

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)StringName=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^/home(.*)$ /%2/? [R=301,NC,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,NC]

 RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1/homepage.html [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that "/name" is redirected and "/Name" is not, is probably due to the fact that Apache's mod_dir is redirecting /name to /name/ because "/var/www/html/name/" is an actual directory, while /var/www/html/Name/ is not.

Apache see's that you are likely trying to access /name/ even when you have specified /name. However, since /Name/ is not a directory, mod_dir doesn't correct it for you.

This can be solved using the rules below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Name(/?)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/name/homepage.html
```

If you also want to capture requests like:

```
http://example.com/Name/something.html
```

And redirect them to:

```
http://example.com/name/something.html
```

You can use this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Name(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/Name(.*) http://example.com/name$1
```

If you want to change ANY Name to name use a RewriteMap:

```
RewriteMap lc "int:tolower"
RewriteRule ^([A-Z].*) "${lc:$1}"
```

This will take any URI that begins with an uppercase letter and transform it to lowercase.